# AdWords ad not approved for "misleading content"

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, google-ads

I have created an HTML5 ad for Google AdWords using Google Web Designer. The ad contains 5 frames, in which every word of motto is showing up word by word, until the motto is complete. Like "This...is...a...motto" and then the phone with a screenshot comes in. The bottom bar contains logo, app name and a button with label Download.

[image: Mockup of ad]

The black box is a representation of a phone with a screenshot of the app. I have used blue as a background, but in the ad it is red.

I have tried 2 times to publish it, and both times it wasn't allowed with reason: "Misleading content".

URL is `www.example.com/download` which redirects you to PlayStore if clicked with Android device, App store if clicked with iOS device or `www.example.com` if clicked with desktop.

Did anyone have the same problem, and does anyone know how to fix it?

EDIT: There is nothing misleading in motto. It says "Stay close with APPNAME"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely your download button.

Google has had big problems with advertisers putting ads on pages about downloading software that have download buttons that download other software or malware: ([image source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vbxq.jpg))

[image]

Because of this, Google is very sensitive about anything that says "download", especially when it looks like a button.

Answer (score 0):

"Misleading content" means that your ad is considered false advertising, or your landing page is unrelated or very poor. It could be many things; the best thing to do is to ask Google, they can check your ad and tell you exactly what you need to change.

Comment: appeal is rejected even tohugh literally all my ad says is that you can search allt he beers in a menu with a single picture which is absolutely TRUE and you won't believe how many hours it took to improve the precision and recall to acceptable levels...